# Using lookbehinds to extract groups of strings in string_extract()

Tags: r, tidyverse, regex-lookarounds, stringr

library(stringr)

I tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804379/stringr-str-extract-how-to-do-positive-lookbehind) but could not make it work for my problem. Using `stringr` I need to extract all the characters following the first string of letters plus a single underscore.

The following extracts exactly what I *don't* want

```
str_extract("mean_q4.8_addiction_critCount", "(^[a-z]*_)")

# [1] "mean_"
```

What I want is

```
# [1] "q4.8_addiction_critCount"
```

Based on the link I inserted above I tried a positive lookbehind

```
str_extract("mean_q4.8_addiction_critCount", "(?<=^[a-z]*_)\\w+")
```

But got the error

```
# Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
#  Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)
```

And I couldn't work out how to constrain the maximum length.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do the opposite instead? Remove everything until first underscore.

```
sub('.*?_', '', 'mean_q4.8_addiction_critCount')
#[1] "q4.8_addiction_critCount"
```

As far as look-behind regex is concerned you can extract everything after first underscore ?

```
stringr::str_extract("mean_q4.8_addiction_critCount", "(?<=_).*")
```

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you, that was very simple in the end. Nothing like a regex to embarrass one.